# Unable to connect redis server on AWS EC2 port 6379

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-vpc

I have two servers on EC2. One hosting my php application and other hosting my redis server. I am managing my php session and data on redis server. So on my php server I gave the ip:port as session save path and got the error FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Connection closed'

I need to open port 6379 on my redis instance for inbound traffic. I opened it by setting a custom TCP setting in AWS security group but still the port is coming closed to outside world. But I am able to listen to the port on redis server itself. Am i Missing anything in the process? Do I need to make any other change somewhere. Please guide me on this. I am very much new to AWS management
On Instance 1: I am using php, Apache and phpredis 
On Instance 2: Using Redis

But I have Memcached installed on the Instance 2 which is connecting via port 11211 without any issue. I have used the same security rules for Redis

Answer (score 7):

By default redis listens only on 127.0.0.1, and you need to explicitly tell redis to listen on other interfaces or for any node. Depending on your distro, this might be somewhere like `/etc/redis.conf`.

On top of that, if you want to let redis listen on all addresses (`0.0.0.0`), you should set `proetected-mode no` in redis.conf.

When you configure redis, **PLEASE for the love of god** make sure on your security group settings, you define that the port is open **only to the IP or security group** of the PHP server that needs to connect to redis, and not to the entire world.

For reference, here's the configuration section from redis.conf about binding:

```
# By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis listens
# for connections from all the network interfaces available on the server.
# It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected interfaces using
# the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one or more IP addresses.
#
# Examples:
# 
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
#
# ~~~ WARNING ~~~ If the computer running Redis is directly exposed to the
# internet, binding to all the interfaces is dangerous and will expose the
# instance to everybody on the internet. So by default we uncomment the
# following bind directive, that will force Redis to listen only into
# the IPv4 lookback interface address (this means Redis will be able to
# accept connections only from clients running into the same computer it
# is running).
#
# IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE INTERFACES
# JUST COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE.
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bind 127.0.0.1

# Protected mode is a layer of security protection, in order to avoid that
# Redis instances left open on the internet are accessed and exploited.
#
# When protected mode is on and if:
#
# 1) The server is not binding explicitly to a set of addresses using the
#    "bind" directive.
# 2) No password is configured.
#
# The server only accepts connections from clients connecting from the
# IPv4 and IPv6 loopback addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1, and from Unix domain
# sockets.
#
# By default protected mode is enabled. You should disable it only if
# you are sure you want clients from other hosts to connect to Redis
# even if no authentication is configured, nor a specific set of interfaces
# are explicitly listed using the "bind" directive.
protected-mode yes
```